# swiftui list text compressed

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
struct DouaView: View {
 @State var duas: English

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        List {
            ForEach(duas.text ,id:\.id){ dua in
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
                    HStack(alignment: .top){
                        Text(dua.arabicText!)
                            .font(.custom("me_quran_volt_newmet.ttf", size: 24))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .layoutPriority(1)

                }.foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(Font.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 20)

                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowBackground(Color("ColorGreen1"))
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle("\(duas.title)", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .modifier(CustomMudifier())
}
}
```

[image]
I have a problem with long text, I tried a lot of things but still the same missing the text is compressed.
can someone help

Comment: this is arabic text

Comment: is that a problem that the text is arabic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `lineLimit(nil)` to some large number `like lineLimit(250)`

If still not working add this modifier after *padding*

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```